# ¿Como soluciono más de una fila en una Subquery dentro de unTrigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo un ejercicio que me pide. Crear un trigger que al borrar una región borre todos los datos relacionados en el resto de tablas, es decir COUNTRIES, DEPARTMENTS, LOCATIONS y EMPLOYEES.

el trigger que he creado es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER EJ7 BEFORE DELETE ON REGIONS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE PRI_REGION FLOAT;
    DECLARE PRI_COUNTRIES CHAR(2);
    DECLARE PRI_LOCATIONS FLOAT;
    DECLARE PRI_DEPARTMENTS FLOAT;
    DECLARE PRI_EMPLOYEES FLOAT;
    SET PRI_REGION=OLD.REGION_ID;
    SET PRI_COUNTRIES=(SELECT COUNTRY_ID FROM COUNTRIES WHERE REGION_ID=PRI_REGION);
    SET PRI_LOCATIONS=(SELECT LOCATION_ID FROM LOCATIONS WHERE COUNTRY_ID=PRI_COUNTRIES);
    SET PRI_DEPARTMENTS=(SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE LOCATION_ID=PRI_LOCATIONS);
    SET PRI_EMPLOYEES=(SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=PRI_DEPARTMENTS);
    DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=PRI_EMPLOYEES;
    DELETE FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=PRI_DEPARTMENTS;
    DELETE FROM LOCATIONS WHERE LOCATION_ID=PRI_LOCATIONS;
    DELETE FROM COUNTRIES WHERE COUNTRY_ID=PRI_COUNTRIES;
END:
```

Y al ejecutar un `DELETE FROM REGIONS WHERE REGION_ID=1:
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Como podría solucionar mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

En sí, un `delete from` no provoca un error de ese tipo.

Tu problema ahi es que estás realizando un `set mivariable =(select varios_valores from tabla);`
la variable solo puede tomar un valor, no varios.

Puedes intentar agregar la clausula "limit 1" en el select, de la siguiente forma: `set mivariable =(select varios_valores from tabla limit 1);`, lo malo es que no cumpliría el cometido de eliminar todos los registros que quieres borrar.

Creo que para tal ejercicio es mas factible utilizar llaves primarias y foraneas "al eliminar - cascada", "al actualizar - cascada".

Por otra parte, las variables que admiten varios valores, son las variables de usuario `SET @mivariable = ElValorQueTuQuieras`.

Answer (score 0):

Creas el Trigger

Insertas los valores en temporales O relacionas todos esos datos y los guardas en una sola temporal, con ello eliminas los datos

Eliminas en base a los datos de las temporales

```
CREATE TRIGGER EJ7 BEFORE DELETE ON REGIONS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE PRI_REGION FLOAT;
    SET PRI_REGION=OLD.REGION_ID;    
    SELECT COUNTRY_ID into #tmpC FROM COUNTRIES WHERE REGION_ID=PRI_REGION;
    SELECT LOCATION_ID into #tmpL FROM LOCATIONS WHERE COUNTRY_ID in (SELECT COUNTRY_ID from #tmpC);
    SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID into #tmpD FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE LOCATION_ID in (SELECT LOCATION_ID from #tmpL);
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID into #tmpE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID in (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID from #tmpD);

    DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID in (select EMPLOYEE_ID from #tmpE);
    DELETE FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID in (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID from #tmpD);
    DELETE FROM LOCATIONS WHERE LOCATION_ID in (SELECT LOCATION_ID from #tmpL);
    DELETE FROM COUNTRIES WHERE COUNTRY_ID in (SELECT COUNTRY_ID from#tmpC);
END:
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta por separado estas querys:

```
SELECT COUNTRY_ID FROM COUNTRIES WHERE REGION_ID=PRI_REGION;
SELECT LOCATION_ID FROM LOCATIONS WHERE COUNTRY_ID=PRI_COUNTRIES;
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE LOCATION_ID=PRI_LOCATIONS;
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=PRI_DEPARTMENTS;
```

Ejecuta una por una cada sentencia, si alguna de esas sentencias te devuelve mas de una fila, quiere decir que debes reformular tu sentencia, esto es debido a que una variable en mysql puede contener unica y exclusivamente un valor ya sea varchar, int, etc...

Una solucion puede ser utilizar `GROUP BY` al final del `WHERE` para poder obtener un solo valor, y no varias filas con el mismo valor que necesitas, aqui te pongo un ejemplo de como podria ir la sentencia:

```
SELECT COUNTRY_ID 
FROM COUNTRIES 
WHERE REGION_ID=PRI_REGION 
GROUP BY COUNTRY_ID;
```

Esa sentencia puede que te traiga mas de una fila, por ponerte un ejemplo:

> Imagina que hay 3 `"COUNTRIES"` que estan en la misma region (espero
> haber entendido bien), pues sin el `GROUP BY`, ahi lo que estas
> haciendo es mostrar 3 filas, y como solo se muestra el `COUNTRY_ID`.
> con `GROUP BY`, haras que los valores repetidos se agrupen, y formaran una sola fila, con un solo valor.

as variables de mysql, solo permiten un solo valor. Por lo que ese puede ser el error que te aparece.